# Why doesn't my bash script read lines from a file when called from a python script?

Tags: python, arrays, bash, call

I am trying to write a small program in bash and part of it needs to be able to get some values from a txt file where the different files are separated by a line, and then either add each line to a variable or add each line to one array.

So far I have tried this:

```
FILE=$"transfer_config.csv"
while read line
do
    MYARRAY[$index]="$line"
    index=$(($index+1))
done < $FILE
echo ${MYARRAY[0]}
```

This just produces a blank line though, and not what was on the first line  of the config file.

I am not returned with any errors which is why I am not too sure why this is happening.

The bash script is called though a python script using `os.system("$HOME/bin/mcserver_config/server_transfer/down/createRemoteFolder")`, but if I simply call it after the python program has made the file which the bash script reads, it works.

I am almost 100% sure it is not an issue with the directories, because `pwd` at the top of the bash script shows it in the correct directory, and the python program is also creating the data file in the correct place.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

I also tried the `subprocess.call("path_to_script", shell=True)` to see if it would make a difference, I know it is unlikely but it didn't.

Comment: What version of bash are you using? I suspect the loop is run in a subshell, so that changes to variables are not seen by the shell that runs the actual script, but newer versions of bash don't do that when redirecting stdin to regular files.(I cannot reproduce the behavior with bash 4.3)

Comment: @Wintermute I am using `GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`. How would I stop what you said in your comment from happening?

Comment: Your code works fine for me.  Is the csv file in the current directory when you run the script?  Also, it might not make any difference but note that `FILE=$"transfer_config.csv"` causes the file name to be translated according to the current locale.  To avoid that, remove the `$`.

Comment: It's unlikely that your bash and mine (mine is 4.3.33) behave differently here. Is the file in the script's working directory and does the user as which the script runs have read permissions for it?

Comment: Just use `mapfile` instead of your while loop: `mapfile -t myarray < "$file"`, and check the content of your array with `declare`: `declare -p myarray`.

Comment: @Wintermute I have just done some testing and what I have found is quite strange. Basically I have a python script that does a load of stuff, then saves what it does to a file. The python script then calls a bash script that does some stuff with that data. If I run the python script and let it call the bash script, when the bash script `echo`s the different parts of the arrays nothing happens. If I then run the bash script separately, it returns what was in the file that the python script produces.

Comment: Sounds like something working-directory-related. Put `pwd` at the top of the shell script and see if it prints the directory where the file can be found. If not, the python script spawns the shell script in a different working directory where it can't find the file.

Comment: @Wintermute `pwd` showed the correct directory. Python can't be spawning it in the wrong place because I checked the file and it changes each time. I will just confirm that I am calling the bash script from my python script correctly by using `os.system("$HOME/bin/mcserver_config/server_transfer/down/createRemoteFolder")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that when calling the bash script from python, having just created the file, you are not really finished with that file: you should either explicitly close the file or use a `with` construct.

Otherwise, the written data is still in any buffer (from the file object, or in the OS, or wherever). Only closing (or at least flushing) the file makes sure the data is indeed in the file.

BTW, instead of `os.system`, you should use the `subprocess` module...

Comment: This sounds like your probably right :) I hadn't closed the file when I called the bash script. i will test it in the morning. I'm pretty certain your right though.